# How to bind ports for docker container in bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'd like to test an application using bitbucket pipelines with a custom docker image running some services. I have a dev docker image which runs all the services I need in order for tests to pass.

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -p 6379:6379 -p 8983:8983 my_dockerhub/image
./start_services.sh
bundle exec rspec
# everything passes
```

I can't seem to find a way to start the container with the right ports bound so the tests to pass.

1. I tried using the container directly using this in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

   ```
   image: 
     name: my_dockerhub/image
     username: $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
     password: $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
     email: $DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL
     # bind ports here somehow?

   pipelines:
     branches:
       '{master, develop, bitbucket_pipelines}':
         - step:
             name: Test
             script:
               - ./start_services.sh
               - sleep 30
               - bundle exec rspec
   ```

   But I get the following error at the `bundle exec rspec` step

   ```
   # Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
   #   Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8983
   ```
2. I tried running the docker container directly within the bitbucket pipeline

   ```
   pipelines:
     branches:
       '{master, develop, bitbucket_pipelines}':
         - step:
             name: Start Docker
             script:
               - docker login -u $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
               - docker run -t -p 3000:3000 -p 6379:6379 -p 8983:8983  my_dockerhub/image
               - ./script/start_services.sh
               - sleep 20
               - bundle exec rspec
   ```

   But the step froze at the `docker run` step.
   I assume this is because I used the -t flag so the command doesn't exit. I was thinking I could possibly use `docker exec` to send commands to the container without running it  but then how would I check the tests have passed?

Comment: `-t` to prevent that the container exits? Did you run it locally?

Comment: Yeah it runs fine locally. I used the ```-t``` flag in my second example, but the pipeline freezes when I run ```docker run -t -p 3000:3000 -p 6379:6379 -p 8983:8983  my_dockerhub/image```

Comment: `-t, --tty                     Allocate a pseudo-TTY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running with `-d detached` flag

`docker run -td -p 3000:3000 -p 6379:6379 -p 8983:8983 my_dockerhub/image
 #       here ^`
 
Containers started in detached mode exit when the root process used to run the container exits. This will prevent the step to freeze at `docker run` stage.

[Docker docs -d flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d)

Comment: Thanks, this was almost it! Bitbucket pipelines doesn't support tty so i needed detached mode with stdin open. The thing that finally got it working was ```docker run -id -p 3000:3000 -p 6379:6379 -p 8983:8983 -v $PWD:$work_dir $my_image```